# Trying to center a card on a page

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment, card

i am not able to center a card on the webpage. I've used Flex to center it, but it is only aligning it horizontally, not vertically.

The output that i was expecting:

[image: Desktop Preview which was provided]

Output that i got:

[image: My Output which is aligned horizontally]

My Code for reference:

```
.container{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

html code:

<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="qr">
        <img src="./images/image-qr-code.png" alt="qr code which leads to Frontend Mentor">
            <div class="content">
            <h3>Improve your front-end skills by building projects</h3>
            <p>Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor and take your coding skills to the next level</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Am i missing something?
I believe i've used the correct logic (justify content & align-items), could there be something wrong with VSCode's live preview extension ?

Comment: Card will be entered vertically only if there is space in the container element. Give some height to the container element, something like: 100vh.

Comment: give height to container as @Yousaf told you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the parent container, which contains the .container class, has a defined height that allows for vertical alignment. If the parent container's height collapses to zero, then the alignment might not work as expected. Here is the CSS that you looking for.

```css
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .qr {
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: Or, as Youssef suggested, using the vh unit for the container's height will fix it: `.container { height: 100vh; }`